# STM32F411 - I2C failure during heavy polling load

Tags: i2c, arm, stm32f4, cortex-m

I have a STM32F411 communicating to 2 peripherals (an IMU - MPU6050 from Invensense, and a LED Driver - CAT3626 from ON Semi) over its 2 I2C buses (one peripheral per bus).

I'm running into a strange issue - if I try accessing the registers on the two devices too quickly, the peripherals eventually stop responding. There is no hard fault - to the microcontroller its as if the device is not connected anymore.

I originally thought it was an issue with the peripheral, however, on deeper investigation it seems the peripherals are not an issue, since if I reinitialize the I2C bus on the STM32F411, I can communicate out to the peripherals again.

Adding a timeout to ensure I only poll each device's register's every 100ms has helped reduce the frequency of the issue, but it still shows up every now and then. I'm hesitant to increase the delay as 100ms already seems like a long time, and any longer and I risk missing critical samples from the IMU.

I'm looking at other workarounds (a timer interrupt to sample the IMU so we have the longest possible delays), but there is not guarantee they will work. I'd rather spend more time understanding the root cause first, but I'm out of ideas as to where to look.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should look at voltages, schematics and pcb layout.

Comment: The I2C peripheral of the STM32F411 is a horrible one. I've encountered many problems during the implementation of the hardware driver (for the F401 but it's the same). Are you using the HAL from ST or have you written your I2C driver yourself? Are you using a DMA or interrupt driven approach? Mine is working now getting values every 20 ms.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - hardware looks good - we're getting really good waves on an oscilloscope

Comment: @Arsenal - I'm using the HAL from ST. Not using DMA or Interrupt - just regular polling